# Curl and wget: why isn't the GET parameter used?

Tags: shell, curl, wget

I am trying to fetch data from [this](http://www.example.com/foo?a=26033) page using wget and curl in PHP. As you can see by using your browser, the default result is 20 items but by setting the GET parameter iip to number x, I can fetch x items, i.e. http:// www.example.com/ foo ?a=26033&b=100

The problem is that the iip parameter only works in browsers. If I try to fetch the last link using wget or curl, only 20 items are returned. Why? Try this at the command-line:

```
curl -O http://www.example.com/foo?a=26033&iip=b
wget http://www.example.com/foo?a=26033&iip=b
```

Why can't I use the GET parameter iip?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try adding quotes:

```
curl -O 'http://www.objektvision.se/annonsorer?ai=26033&iip=100'
wget 'http://www.objektvision.se/annonsorer?ai=26033&iip=100'
```

The `&` has special functionality on the command line which is likely causing the issues.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that works from the shell! The problem is that I am actually using this from php, so I guess that I just have to enclose the curl call in quotes?

Answer (score 3):

Try quoting the argument. At least in `cmd`, `&` is used to delimit two commands that are run individually.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to enclose your URL in either " or ', since the & has a special meaning in shellscript... That'll give you:

```
curl -O "http://www.objektvision.se/annonsorer?ai=26033&iip=100"
wget "http://www.objektvision.se/annonsorer?ai=26033&iip=100"
```

Answer (score 3):

`&` is a reserved word in shell. Just escape it like this `\&`