# Use cURL to download a file from an automated download page

Tags: html, linux, macos, curl, download

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically download and install the latest version of certain programs for me. I was wondering if there was some easy way to download the latest program for a website.

For example, take the Firefox download page: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2

Over there, it shows "Your download should download automatically" and it downloads the latest file.

Yet, when I use `curl` to try and download the file, all I get is the source code for the page. Is there any way to just download the file that the website gives me?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try adding quotes? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713638/curl-and-wget-why-isnt-the-get-parameter-used>

Comment: Sadly, I did...

Answer (score 0):

Those are usually implemented via a redirect, so

curl -L https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2 -o lastest_firefox.exe

should work.

(I can't test it right now, my command line won't cross the firewall).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... but it just tries to download the html. In some of them I could scan the headers and get the dl link that way, but it doesn't seem to work for all websites :(